# bootstrap getDate returns different from the obvious

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I could not understand what is happening.

Here is how I render the html in the .cshtml View

```
<input class="date input-sm" type="text" id="CertificateFrom" value="@(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1).ToShortDateString())">
```

and here is the html itself:

```
<input class="date input-sm" type="text" id="CertificateFrom" value="1.1.2015 г.">
```

**This is what's bothering me**

```
$('#CertificateFrom').val()
```

> "1.1.2015 г."

```
$('#CertificateFrom').data('datepicker').viewDate
```

> Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)

```
$('#CertificateFrom').data('datepicker').getDate()  
//$('#CertificateFrom').datepicker('getDate') returns the same result
```

> Wed Dec 31 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)

**Q:** Why is this happening? And how to correctly get js date object